Can't Open An Object in Javascript
My code is below.  This is for a Google Map where you click a spot on the map and it shows in a left pane info from the point of the click.  I want to use the lattitude and longitude in my Javascript to do other processing.  I see the code returns an object, and when I open it via clicking on it in the Console Log I can see the data that the object contains.  I can't seem to open the object with Javascript to read data from it.  I am trying to do this near "alert(response);" in my code.  I have read solutions on the internet but none have produced anything but blanks while I can see a lot of data by manually reviewing the Console after I click.  Thanks for the help!
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
 @license
 Copyright 2019 Google LLC. All Rights Reserved.
 SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
-->
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Geocoding Service</title>
    <script>
      /**
       * @license
       * Copyright 2019 Google LLC. All Rights Reserved.
       * SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
       */
      let map;
      let marker;
      let geocoder;
      let responseDiv;
      let response;

      function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
          zoom: 7,
          center: { lat: 44.630978, lng: -86.072480 },
          mapTypeControl: false,
        });
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

        const inputText = document.createElement("input");

        inputText.type = "text";
        inputText.placeholder = "Enter a location";

        const submitButton = document.createElement("input");

        submitButton.type = "button";
        submitButton.value = "Geocode";
        submitButton.classList.add("button", "button-primary");

        const clearButton = document.createElement("input");

        clearButton.type = "button";
        clearButton.value = "Clear";
        clearButton.classList.add("button", "button-secondary");
        response = document.createElement("pre");
        response.id = "response";
        response.innerText = "";
        responseDiv = document.createElement("div");
        responseDiv.id = "response-container";
        responseDiv.appendChild(response);

        const instructionsElement = document.createElement("p");

        instructionsElement.id = "instructions";
        instructionsElement.innerHTML =
          "<strong>Instructions</strong>: Enter an address in the textbox to geocode or click on the map to reverse geocode.";
        map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(inputText);
        map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(submitButton);
        map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(clearButton);
        map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_TOP].push(
          instructionsElement
        );
        map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_TOP].push(responseDiv);
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map,
        });
        map.addListener("click", (e) => {
          geocode({ location: e.latLng });
        });
        submitButton.addEventListener("click", () =>
          geocode({ address: inputText.value })
        );
        clearButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
          clear();
        });
        clear();
      }

      function clear() {
        marker.setMap(null);
      }

      function geocode(request) {
        clear();
        geocoder
          .geocode(request)
          .then((result) => {
            const { results } = result;

            map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
            marker.setPosition(results[0].geometry.location);
            marker.setMap(map);
            response.innerText = JSON.stringify(result, null, 2);
            return results;
          })
          .catch((e) => {
            alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + e);
          });

          
          alert(response);
          console.log("response =");
          console.log(response);


          function readPreElement() {
            const preElement = document.getElementById("response"); // Replace "myPre" with the ID of your <pre> element
            const textContent = preElement.textContent;

            console.log("text content = " + textContent); // Output the content to the console
            // You can do whatever you want with the textContent here
          }

          readPreElement();



//          const preElement = document.getElementById("response");
//          const content = preElement.textContent;

//          console.log("content = " + content);

          var _html = document.getElementsByTagName('pre')[0].innerHTML;
          console.log("_html = " + _html);

            alert("_html is type: " + typeof(_html));
            alert("_html is length of: " + _html.length);

          var _query = document.querySelector('pre').innerHTML;
          console.log(_query);

          alert("_query is type: " + typeof(_query));
            alert("_query is length of: " + _query.length);



          //alert(typeof(map));
          //alert(response.innerText.length);
          //console.log(map);
          //report_it();

      }

      window.initMap = initMap;


    </script>
    <style>
      /**
       * @license
       * Copyright 2019 Google LLC. All Rights Reserved.
       * SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
       */
      /**
       * Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div element
       * that contains the map. 
       */
      #map {
        height: 50%;
      }

      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html,
      body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }

      input[type="text"] {
        background-color: #fff;
        border: 0;
        border-radius: 2px;
        box-shadow: 0 1px 4px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
        margin: 10px;
        padding: 0 0.5em;
        font: 400 18px Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;
        overflow: hidden;
        line-height: 40px;
        margin-right: 0;
        min-width: 25%;
      }

      input[type="button"] {
        background-color: #fff;
        border: 0;
        border-radius: 2px;
        box-shadow: 0 1px 4px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
        margin: 10px;
        padding: 0 0.5em;
        font: 400 18px Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;
        overflow: hidden;
        height: 40px;
        cursor: pointer;
        margin-left: 5px;
      }
      input[type="button"]:hover {
        background: rgb(235, 235, 235);
      }
      input[type="button"].button-primary {
        background-color: #1a73e8;
        color: white;
      }
      input[type="button"].button-primary:hover {
        background-color: #1765cc;
      }
      input[type="button"].button-secondary {
        background-color: white;
        color: #1a73e8;
      }
      input[type="button"].button-secondary:hover {
        background-color: #d2e3fc;
      }

      #response-container {
        background-color: #fff;
        border: 0;
        border-radius: 2px;
        box-shadow: 0 1px 4px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
        margin: 10px;
        padding: 0 0.5em;
        font: 400 18px Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;
        overflow: hidden;
        overflow: auto;
        max-height: 50%;
        max-width: 90%;
        background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.95);
        font-size: small;
      }

      #instructions {
        background-color: #fff;
        border: 0;
        border-radius: 2px;
        box-shadow: 0 1px 4px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
        margin: 10px;
        padding: 0 0.5em;
        font: 400 18px Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;
        overflow: hidden;
        padding: 1rem;
        font-size: medium;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBxeRjDvCOd2QP-12ayt-vg1YZ71WPcwSk&callback=initMap&v=weekly&solution_channel=GMP_CCS_geocodingservice_v2"
      defer
      ></script>
    

      <script src="final_NWS.js">
      </script>;

      <div id="profile">
        temperatureString;
      </div>
    
  



  </body>
</html>


Which object are you trying to open? Are you talking about the object in return results;? That would be returned to the next .then() function in the chain, but you don't have another .then().

response is a <pre> HTML element. It just contains the JSON.stringify text, you can't really interact with that.

Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call is what you're looking for, but it's unclear. Can you simplify the [mre] to just the part relevant to the question?

response is what I was after...  I can see it's contents in the Console but you are reaching my conclusion!

What do you mean by "opening" response? It's not a JavaScript object with useful properties to access, other than its innerText.

It contains the lattitude and longitude of the point of the map clicked...  perhaps "read" or "interigate" is a better term

The issue in this is, how to extract the latitude and longitude from the result object returned by the geocode function. The response object is being set as the inner text of a <pre> tag, but that is just for display purposes. To use the latitude and longitude programmatically, you can directly access it from the results array.
I am adding the updated code:
function geocode(request) {
  clear();
  geocoder.geocode(request).then((result) => {
      const {
        results
      } = result;

      if (results.length > 0) {
        const location = results[0].geometry.location;
        const lat = location.lat(); // Get latitude
        const lng = location.lng(); // Get longitude

        // Update the map and marker
        map.setCenter(location);
        marker.setPosition(location);
        marker.setMap(map);

        // Display response in the <pre> tag
        response.innerText = JSON.stringify(result, null, 2);

        // Log the lat and lng for further processing
        console.log("Latitude:", lat);
        console.log("Longitude:", lng);

        // Use lat and lng for other processing
        alert(`Latitude: ${lat}, Longitude: ${lng}`);
      } else {
        alert("No results found!");
      }
      return results;
    })
    .catch((e) => {
      alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + e);
    });
}


Thank you!  Thank you!  Thank you!  Your solution worked and I was able to complete the section of my webpage development that I was working on.

lets focus on just the thing you're trying to understand:

response is an HTML element "document.createElement("pre")" not an object

.then((result) result is the "response" object

.then((result) is a resolver of a promise you cannot access 'result' outside of the promise chain
let response;
 ...
 response = document.createElement("pre"); // html element
 ...

 function geocode(request) {
 clear();
 geocoder
   .geocode(request)
   .then((result) => {
     const { results } = result; // response object

     ...

     response.innerText = JSON.stringify(result, null, 2);
     return results;
   })



heres your confusing part
   alert(response);

because the alert is outside of the promise chain it has alerted before the response was completed so it has nothing in it yet.
put the alert inside the promise chain and you'll soon see whats going on
function geocode(request) {
  clear();
  geocoder
    .geocode(request)
    .then((result) => {
      const { results } = result; // object

      ...

      response.innerText = JSON.stringify(result, null, 2);

      // alert(response);
      console.log(response) // use the console, alert only support basic strings

      return results;
    })

   ...

last tip is to consider learning the syntax for async await, it makes this type of task much easier to read
